# Regex for double slash comments

Tags: regex

I need a regex that will match a double-slash comment on the end of a line, while ignoring it if is enclosed in quotes:

```
something something // match this and the double slash
this address: "https://foo" but don't match this
```

I want to capture the comment along with the slashes in a capturing group.

I originally simply had `.*(/\/\/.*)`, but that fails in case of quotes and I haven't managed to find how to do that.

Comment: `[^"]*? (\/\/.*)` this seems to be working for the examples you've provided.

Comment: @InspectorGadget it works for those specific examples but it also matches `so "// what"`.

Answer (score 0):

How about using it like this:

```
/(?:\s|^)(?<comment>\/\/(?<text>.+))/gm
```

**Rule:** space or nothing (line start) should be there before `//`

#### Accepted examples

```
// some thing
 // some thing
something something // match this and the double slash
foo bar // "hello"
```

#### Not accepted examples:

```
h// some things
this address: "https://foo" but don't match this
```

[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/NdhWYG/1)

Answer (score 0):

```js
let s=`something something // match this and the double slash\nthis address: "https://foo" but don't match this`
console.log(s.match(/\"? [\/]{2}.+/ig))
//second example with EOL sign
let s=[`something something // match this and the double slash`,`this address: "https://foo" but don't match this`]
console.log(s[0].match(/\"? [\/]{2}.+$/ig))
console.log(s[1].match(/\"? [\/]{2}.+$/ig))
```

but You still have to stick some argument rules, like at least one space between https://foo/foo //comment